# using mod_rewrite to get rid of question mark

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

alright... so I have this css bundler, using the following link:

http://www.example.com/min/?b=wp-content/themes/mytheme&f=style.css,boxes.css,mods.css,scripts.css

Parameter b is the css folder url and parameter f is the css files to get.

However, to help out my cache, I want the question mark gone. If possible, something like:

http://www.example.com/min/b=wp-content/themes/mytheme&f=style.css,boxes.css,mods.css,scripts.css

I tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?b=$1 [L]
```

Needless to say, It did not work.

Comment: It seems the problem lies with the slashes in the b value

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are going to loop, you can try adding a condition in front of your rule so that it looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?b=$1 [L]
```

But it seems, based on your example URLs, you want something more like this:

```
RewriteRule ^min/b=(.*)$ index.php?b=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an unusual thing to do where you want to get rid of `?` from query string but want to keep ampersand i.e. `&`.

Anyway if that's what you really want then you can put this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^min/b=([^;]*);f=(.*)$ min/?b=$1&f=$2 [L]
```

This rule will internally redirect `http://www.example.com/min/b=wp-content/themes/mytheme;f=style.css,boxes.css,mods.css,scripts.css` to `http://www.example.com/min/?b=wp-content/themes/mytheme&f=style.css,boxes.css,mods.css,scripts.css`

Comment: The problem was that my cache wouldn't store files with a "?" in their url. How would I go about removing the ampersand as well?

Comment: Oh so what do you want your final URI to be?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be conventional

Comment: ok check my updated answer to see if that is workable for you.

Comment: Hm... I just end up on my 404 page

Comment: The one in your updated answer, using a semi colon instead of ampersand

Comment: That URL, I have posted after testing only and it was working fine here. Can you paste matching error.log lines here.

Comment: There are no errors... Could it be interference with my wordpress installation? It uses mod_rewrite

Comment: Yes it could very well be interference from WP code however the rule I suggested above will trigger for a URI that has /min/ at the start. Can you enable RewriteLog in httpd.con to debug it.